# dont know as how to mount the file-system in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, mount

I am new to ubuntu , please help me i need create /data and mount this file system /dev/sdb 
I have no clue as to how to do it . I read about mount and unmount , but I am still unable to create.
Below is the current structure .

Pdpie@ubuntu:/dev$ df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        18G  4.0G   13G  24% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            984M  4.0K  984M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  1.5M  198M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            994M  152K  994M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
```

> I wanted to see like this below

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        18G  4.0G   13G  24% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            984M  4.0K  984M   1% /dev
tmpfs           199M  1.5M  198M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            994M  152K  994M   1% /run/shm
none            100M   44K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb        50M                   /data
```

Can anyone please help me step by step.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your mount point first:

```
sudo mkdir /data
```

Then mount the `sdb1` (if sdb1 is what you want) to it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /data
```

Done

**PS:** To check which one you want to mount run `sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: I need to create /dev/sdb partition , could you please help me with the syntax

Answer (score 0):

What about the following?

```
# mkdir /data
# mount /dev/sdb1 /data
```

If you don't have `/dev/sdb<number>`, you'll have to create partitions with e.g. `parted` or `fdisk`.

Comment: I have create the partion , but when i try to mount it throws me a error asking for a file system type . /dev/sda5        37752832    41940991     2094080   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Comment: root@ubuntu:~# mount -t ext /dev/sda5 /data
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext'

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps 
1.Create a directory which you want that is mkdir /data

2.Then you will use mount command to mount /data directory to sdb1 which is like this mount /dev/sdb1

3.Then to take it immediate effect use this command  mount -a

4.Then to check it you can use  df-h